# Images disappear after few hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

I want to create little ticket system : http://ticketsystemkm.herokuapp.com/ 
I got posters for movies to display them on main site. 
When i make new movie everything works good, but after few hours images disappear.
Maybe someone had similar problem and know how to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guessing your images are user uploads via Paperclip, or something of the like, to your public folder, which is why they're disappearing. If your app doesn't receive any traffic for 15 minutes or so, the VM it lives on is destroyed, and the public folder goes along with it.

You need to store your assets on S3, or some of other CDN. The other option is to check the relevant assets into version control into app/assets/images.

A more detailed explanation (and solution) can be found here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

Comment: I was under the impression that this was only the case when you re-pushed the code. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Comment: I need to test this, I really think the files are maintained until a redeploy of code

Answer (score 0):

Issue can happen if you change `default_url` of uploader or uploaded files has been deleted

You should check something:
- image path in website
- default_url in uploader
- file in that path exist

I think we cannot store files in heroku, maybe it's cleared frequently
If upload file is cleared by heroku, you should store it external(S3, Azure Storage, Google Cloud Storage, ...)