# Heroku error when using Paperclip gem in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

My project is about an online Shopping site.
I use paperclip gem to updload image.
My problem is: I can upload images,show them.But after 4-5 hours it cant show image.It doesn't images.
What should I do to save Images all time ?

Comment: heroku doesn't help you out to store images in your public folder, you need amazon s3 services or other external services to do that

Comment: so what should I do ? I just can do in free hosting

Comment: you can use amazon or cloud storage which has free storage upto few gb, have to go through that documentation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Images disappear after few hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640933/images-disappear-after-few-hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku deletes files in your public folder every time it instantiates a new VM (usually after your app has been dormant for a few minutes.)

You need to store your images in a place where they will persist when a VM is destroyed. Heroku has a tutorial on how to store the files at S3 here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

Answer (score 0):

- Sign up for an AWS S3 account. (Its really cheap within normal usage imo)
- Use [Fog](https://github.com/fog/fog). There is [a guide here](http://jessicag.github.io/Using-Paperclip-AWS-and-Fog/).
- Sign the S3 image urls when serving to frontend, to expire in 4-5 hours.

Comment: Sorry, Is this way free ?